# Spring DatastoreRepository beans cannot be resolved at runtime, but Intellij shows no errors when building

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-datastore

I have been migrating a project to use Spring DataStore Repositories from the awful manual implementation. A POC was run, and everything was fine.

However, when I replaced the old repository packages with the new ones, I am getting the following dependency error when I try to run the application:

```
2019-10-23 15:46:20.409 DEBUG 8416 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : Application failed to start due to an exception

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ps_test_tool_datastore.repos.user_repos.RoleRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1253) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:874) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:778) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at ps_test_tool_datastore.Application.main(Application.java:16) [classes/:na]

2019-10-23 15:46:20.409 ERROR 8416 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in ps_test_tool_datastore.services.user_services.RoleServices required a bean of type 'ps_test_tool_datastore.repos.user_repos.RoleRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'ps_test_tool_datastore.repos.user_repos.RoleRepository' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Underlying Object:

```
package ps_test_tool_datastore.repos.pojos.user_info;

import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.core.mapping.Entity;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Reference;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@Entity(name="Role")
public class Role implements Comparable<Role>
{
    //variables

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String role;
    private String description;

    @Reference
    private ArrayList<Privilege> privileges;

    //booleans for form validation
    @Transient
    private boolean roleFormError;

    @Transient
    private boolean roleEmptyError;

    @Transient
    private boolean descEmptyError;

    @Transient
    private boolean privEmptyError;

    public Role(){}

    public Role(String role, String description, ArrayList<Privilege> privileges)
    {
        this.role = role;
        this.description = description;
        this.privileges = privileges;

    }
```

The Repository:

```
package ps_test_tool_datastore.repos.user_repos;

import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.repository.DatastoreRepository;
import ps_test_tool_datastore.repos.pojos.user_info.Role;


public interface RoleRepository extends DatastoreRepository<Role, Long>
{
    Role findByRole(String role);

    Role findByDescription(String description);

}
```

And the service:

```
package ps_test_tool_datastore.services.user_services;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import ps_test_tool_datastore.repos.user_repos.PrivilegeRepository;
import ps_test_tool_datastore.repos.user_repos.RoleRepository;
import ps_test_tool_datastore.repos.pojos.user_info.Privilege;
import ps_test_tool_datastore.repos.pojos.user_info.Role;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class RoleServices //TODO: update template: implements RoleServiceTemplate 
{
    private RoleRepository roleDAOImplementation;

    private PrivilegeRepository privilegeDAOImplementation;

    public RoleServices(RoleRepository roleDAOImplementation, PrivilegeRepository privilegeDAOImplementation)
    {
        this.roleDAOImplementation = roleDAOImplementation;
        this.privilegeDAOImplementation = privilegeDAOImplementation;
    }

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RoleServices.class);



    //@Override
    public Role createRole(Role role) {

        //does a role with this name exist
        try
        {
            Role tempRole = roleDAOImplementation.findByRole(role.getRole());
            if (tempRole!=null)
            {
                logger.debug("Role with name {} already exists", role.getRole());
                return role;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.debug("Role with name {} not found", role.getRole());
        }

        //persist the Role to the database
        try{
            roleDAOImplementation.save(role);
            logger.debug("Role with ID " + role.getId() + " created");
        }

        catch (Exception e){
            logger.error("Unexpected Error creating Role");
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return role;
    }

    //@Override
    public Role getRoleByID(Long id) {


        try{

            Role roleResult = roleDAOImplementation.findById(id).get();
            logger.info("Role number {} returned successfully", roleResult.getId());

            return roleResult;

        }


        catch (Exception e){
            logger.error("Unexpected Error finding Role");
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);

            return null;
        }


    }

    //@Override
    public boolean updateRole(Role role) {

        //try to persist rol;e to DB
        try{
            roleDAOImplementation.save(role);
            logger.info("Role with ID {} updated", role.getId());
            return true;
        }


        catch (Exception e){
            logger.error("Unexpected Error updating Role");
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);

            return false;
        }

    }

    //@Override
    public List<Role> getAllRoles() {

        List<Role> roleList = new ArrayList<>();

        try{
            Iterable<Role> roles = roleDAOImplementation.findAll();
            for (Role role: roles)
                roleList.add(role);
        }

        catch (Exception e){
            logger.error("Unexpected Error getting Roles");
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return roleList;
    }

    public List<Privilege> getRolePrivs(Role role){

        return role.getPrivileges();

    }

    public Role addRolePrivs(Collection<Privilege> privileges, Role role){


        ArrayList<Privilege> privilegeArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Privilege privilege: privileges)
            privilegeArrayList.add(privilege);

        role.setPrivileges(privilegeArrayList);

        try{
            roleDAOImplementation.save(role);
            logger.info("Privileges for Role with ID {} updated", role.getId());
        }


        catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("Unexpected Error updating Role");
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }


        return role;
    }


    public Role getRoleByName(String role)
    {

        try
        {
            return roleDAOImplementation.findByRole(role);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the implementation for RoleRepository interface? The error is pointing to that it hasn't found any Bean implementing this interface.

Comment: According to the Spring documentation for cloud-gcp-data-datastore, there is not ned to implement the class:

"Spring Data generates a working implementation of the specified interface, which can be autowired into an application."

My POC used the same method and worked fine. 

I did it slightly wrong the first time, and have an answered question about it, so I know that bit works.

Old question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57993447/datastorerepository-able-to-save-objects-but-all-find-methods-throw-a-null-poin

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this issue is clearly indicated in the Spring error :

> expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency

As the bean trying to be picked up automatically by classpath scanning and it is defined correctly I would say that **it may be defined in a package that is not scanned by Spring**. It may be simply out of the Spring context. Do you have any configuration like this?

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("some.random.package")
public class ContextWithJavaConfig {
...
}
```

If this issue is not related with the location where are you scanning the Spring components, I would recommend you to offer Spring some basic implementation for this repository, also. Even though, I know theoretically is unnecessary, just give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @andrei-tigau. 

My application class in the "ps_test_tool_datastore" package, and that has the @SpringBootApplication annotation, so I would have expected it to resolve itself. 

I have added `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "ps_test_tool_datastore")` to be sure, but to no avail.

I will try the implementation idea and report back...

Comment: Update : try to add @Repository annotation to your RoleRepository interface